# MySQL Merging tag records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge, tags

I have a tag system that has multiple relations. Sometimes there is similar tags that should be merged into one.

Lets call tagA the tag that should be merged, and so disappear, and tagB the tag that will now assume the tagA relations.

For clarification, what I need is that: Every single entity that was previous related to tagA become now related with tagB and then remove tagA.

The basic structure is something like this:

```
tag
---------------
tag_id

description



tag_news
---------------
tag_news_id

tag_id

news_id



tag_pages
---------------
tag_pages_id

tag_id

pages_id
```

and so on...

I know I could simply:

**1)** Update all tables that relates with 'tag' table changing tagA's id for tagB's id.

**2)** Remove tagA from 'tag' table.

But the relations with the tag system keeps increasing, and I would like a solution that I didn't need to inform every table that is being update in query.

I thought of using UPDATE cascade, but I wouldn't be able to update tagA's  id for tagB's id at 'tag' table  because I would end with two records with the same primary key.

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What about:
1. inserting TagB as new tag;
2. Update all tables changing TagA to TagB;
3. Delete TagA from Tags table

Comment: That would work, with two buts. First, tagB already exists, second it keeps the problem having to update the code every time a new relation appears. But I'm starting to think that I will not have a magic solution. Thanks!